# Azure Web PubSub disconnected event doesn't work on closed web socket

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azure-web-pubsub

When I close the connection with a web socket by ws.close() on a client side. The disconnected Azure Function is not triggered. Please help! My binding is:

```
{
"bindings": [{
"type": "webPubSubTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"name": "data",
"hub": "hubName",
"eventName": "disconnected",
"eventType": "system"
}]
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.